# Uncaught ReferenceError ao passar valores via JS

Tags: javascript

estou tentando passa uma string e um int num JS para ele me devolver num modal e me vem esse erro abaixo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Tentando passar aqui os valores aqui na td para o JS e ele precisa me devolver isso no modal.
obs: utilizando java spring para trazer esse valores do banco

```
<td><a href='#' onclick="setaDadosModal(nome, numero)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con-close-modal-altera"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

Meu modal

```
<div id="con-close-modal-altera" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Alterar Modalidade</h4>
                    </div>
                    <form name="alterarModalidade" action="alteraModalidades" method="post" role="form"> 
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input required="" name="idModalidades" type="hidden" id="alteraIdModalidade" class="form-control"> 
                                        <input required="true" name="nomeModalidadeTemp" type="text" id="alteraNomeModalidadeTemp" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Digite a modalidade a ser alterada" maxlength="30"> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            <button type="submit" onclick="return alterarModal()" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect waves-light">Alterar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Meu JS

```
function setaDadosModal(AltnomeModalidade, AltidModalidade) {
document.getElementById('alteraNomeModalidadeTemp').value = AltnomeModalidade;
document.getElementById('alteraIdModalidade').value = AltidModalidade;}
```

Meu Erro

> modalidades:258 Uncaught ReferenceError: aaaa is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (modalidades:258)

Linha 258 que o erro se refere

```
<td><a href='#' onclick="setaDadosModal(aaaa, 107)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con-close-modal-altera"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No HTML referido por você, que é a fonte do erro:

```
 <td><a href='#' onclick="setaDadosModal(aaaa, 107)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con-close-modal-altera"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

Vamos extrair e nos focar nessa parte (*que é o JavaScript*):

```
setaDadosModal(aaaa, 107)
```

Note que no primeiro parâmetro, você passou uma variável, no entanto, como essa variável (`aaaa`) não existe, o erro está sendo jogado.

Provavelmente, ao invés de passar no primeiro parâmetro uma variável, você queria passar uma **[`string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)**, mas para isso, você deveria ter feito:

```
setaDadosModal('aaaa', 107) // Recomendado
```

Ou em alternativa:

```
var aaaa = 'aaaa'; setaDadosModal(aaaa, 107)
```

Ficando então, no HTML:

```
 <td><a href='#' onclick="setaDadosModal('aaaa', 107)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con-close-modal-altera"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

Ou:

```
 <td><a href='#' onclick="var aaaa = 'aaaa'; setaDadosModal(aaaa, 107)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con-close-modal-altera"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela ajuda e explicação, era exatamente isso, que errinho bobo.